# How can I extract certain color with its position from a jpeg?

Tags: r

By library of 'JPEG', we can extract RGB matrix from a jpeg file. If I know the certain color in #RRGGBB format, how can I get the positions of the color points?

```
library(jpeg)
IMGMX <- readJPEG("sample.jpg") %>% melt %>% dcast(Var1+Var2~Var3, value.var = "value")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Re-scale data to [0, 255]

```
IMGMX[, 3:5] <- 255 * IMGMX[, 3:5]
```

## Convert #RRGGBB to R, G, B coordinates

```
clr <- '#652d90'
r <- col2rgb(clr)[1]
g <- col2rgb(clr)[2]
b <- col2rgb(clr)[3]
```

## Print matches

```
IMGMX[IMGMX$`1` == r & IMGMX$`2` == g & IMGMX$`3` == b, 1:2]
```

This will give you a dataframe comprised of 2 columns (width and height) and of n rows, corresponding to the n pixels in the original image that have the color 'clr'.